# Excel - generate from pattern?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there some sort of mechanism in Excel that lets you create data using a specific pattern? Something like a regex that does all the possibilities.

For example:

NET[0:31]_[P/N]

Would generate

```
NET0_P
NET0_N
NET1_P
NET1_N
```

and so forth.

Comment: @Excellll's answer will work fine, but will change values if the rows are re-sorted, added or otherwise modified. If you want something more flexible and where values become "locked", let us know and we can work on something a little more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's nothing built in specifically for this purpose.  You can, however, get clever and use a formula to generate all the possibilities.  In `A1`, enter the following and fill down (to `A64`):

```
="NET"&INT((ROW()-1)/2)&"_"&IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),"N","P")
```

Comment: note that if you need it to start in a different place, the easiest way is to put this formula in a separate spreadsheet, then copy the values instead of the formulas